# Why won’t the comment notification go away?

Tags: support, bug

Somebody please delete the comment notification to me. It is not going away after much effort.

Comment: What do you mean? An email notification?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking. I mean the red circle with the number 1 over the inbox icon.

Answer (score 1):

As it is tedious to click on every single comment notification, the StackExchange team has, luckily, provided us with a possibility to mark all of them as read.

First, you need to click on the inbox in the header:

[image]

Afterwards, in the dropdown menu that opens, you can mark all at once as read and the notifications disappear:

[image]

Comment: That worked. Thanks!